# phone number format checking javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have made a website with JS and php and as you can see below is my code at paste bin, I have looked around and seen regular expressions but I don't know how to use them or what I should use exactly....But basically I want to just allow the user to enter north american phone numbers and if they enter anything else then give them a message to enter a valid phone number...

Below is my code to help you understand what I have..What I need and what my site's interface looks like...

http://pastebin.com/8NwURm0G

possible phone numbers user can enter are 9058554678 OR 4167641689...

This is how the the list looks:

http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/Edit.php

Comment: Do you want to allow dashes, dots, spaces, parentheses? What about 10 digits vs 7 digits? Do you want to allow the leading 1 (country code)? Did you want it restricted to area codes 905 and 416?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth reading up on regular expressions before using them, since they can be a little tricky and unintuitive.

Good tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Based on what you list as a valid input, you're looking to see if the user entered in 10 digits. This can be done by checking if a character is a digit, and then seeing if there are 10 of them, which would be the regular expression: [0-9]{10}. Example on how to use:

```
var myRegEx = /[0-9]{10}/;
var itemsToTest = ["9058554678","abc"];

for (var ii=0;ii<itemsToTest.length;ii++) {
    if ( myRegEx.test(itemsToTest[ii]) ) {
        alert(itemsToTest[ii] + " is valid!");
    }
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/87ea8/

Answer (score 1):

Here is regex that I have laying around to only match 10 digit NA numbers, based off the [NANP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan)

```
/(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})/
```

Comment: I'd honestly just regex out anything that's not a number and anything past 3 digits then check that against every area code in the U.S. It'd be so much more readable.

Comment: how do i use this expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d{10}$
```

That matches 10-digit numbers.

```
^1?\d{10}$
```

That matches 10-digit numbers with an optional 1 at the front.

```
^(?:1-?\s*)?(?:\(?:\d{3}\)|\d{3})\s*-?\d{4}$
```

That matches digit groupings like `1-444-555-6666` or `(444) 555-6666`, and some related ones.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on google yielded the following result. You might want to combine it with mitchellhislop's answer.

```
function isPhoneNumber(s)
{

 // Check for correct phone number
 rePhoneNumber = new RegExp(/^\([1-9]\d{2}\)\s?\d{3}\-\d{4}$/);

 if (!rePhoneNumber.test(s)) {
      alert("Phone Number Must Be Entered As: (555) 555-1234");
      return false;
 }

return true;
}
```